# Search an array of objects for specific key having a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I want to retrieve all rows from a table in MySQL table where there is a JSON column called `items` with content like this:

```js
[{"code":"MH005","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"28.00"},{"code":"MH027","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"28.00"}]
[{"code":"MH027","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"30.00"}]
[{"code":"MH024","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"28.00"},{"code":"MH028","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"28.00"},{"code":"MH027","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"28.00"}]
[{"code":"MH028","qte":1,"totalpriceItem":"30.00"}]
```

Now i want to be able to select all the row where the key `code` has the value `MH027`.

I've tried this but without success:

```
SELECT *
FROM `transactions`
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`item`, 'MH027', '$[*].code')
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And what exactly do you mean by `Items.Row1`, `Items.Row2` etc

Comment: Mysql version : mysql 8.0.18 & mariaDB 10.4.10

it mean the content of JSON field in each row inserted in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to use [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(item, '{"code": "MH027"}', '$')
```

The second parameter must be valid JSON. You could use `JSON_OBJECT('code', 'MH028')` if the value is dynamic or could contain special characters.

Comment: Hey 
sorry to bother again i know this is an answered question but i just want to know how can i tweak it so i can select all the transactions that they had item start with "MH%"

Comment: That would be a different question. I would use `JSON_TABLE`.

Comment: can you point me please ?